# Index of a language and its reversal

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

The index of a language is the number of Myhill-Nerode classes that it has. It is also equal to the number of states in the minimal DFA for the language. What is an example of a language that has a different index from its reversal?

Comment: [This one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24504/is-the-reversal-of-a-minimal-dfa-also-minimal?rq=1) contains an example too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $k$th letter equals $a$, for fixed $k$, assuming a two letter alphabet.

This generic answer is made precise in the comment by @AntonTrunov below.

Comment: Not for arbitrary $k$ though. The number of states of the minimal DFA for the original language would be $k+2$ and for its reversal the number of states is $\frac{|\Sigma|^k - 1}{|\Sigma|-1} + 1$. So, for example, if $|\Sigma| = 2$ and $k = 2$, then the number of states for those DFAs equals $4$ (in both cases).

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks. That is *very* precise.

Comment: Thank you. It would be *very* precise, if I added "assuming $|\Sigma|>1$" :)

Comment: @HendrikJan Add detail to you answer on the duplicate?

Comment: @Raphael I followed your suggestion. Should we delete this answer?

Comment: @HendrikJan Thanks! Your call. Does it do harm (eg. because it lacks the details)? If not, it can stay.

Comment: I don't see where the denominator of $|\Sigma| - 1$ comes from, but then I also don't see the necessity of the term $|\Sigma|^k - 1$. If you encode all $k$ last seen characters, you need exactly the $|\Sigma|^k$ states you get with that expression for $|\Sigma| = 2$. If you only encode "position was $a$ (resp. $\bar a$)", you can always make do with $2^k$ states whenever $|\Sigma| \geq 2$.